# Getting contentLength of a chuncked HttpServletResponse within a Servlet Filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I setting up a Servlet Request Filter to intercept requests to a tomcat application. The application's responses happen to be `Transfer-Encoding: ***chunked***` hence the method `*httpServletResponse.getContentLengthLong*` returns `-1` which means content length is not available in the response header.

Is there a workaround to get the contentLength of these chunked servlet responses in a servlet filter context?

Comment: It probably is chunked as the content length was not set in the headers prior to streaming the output. Unless store all the output and at the end - after a delay - send the actual data, nothing can be done. And that would be a terrible solution too. Better repair the application providing a long content length.

Comment: The response is chunked because it's meant for streaming as it's a probably too big. So the application is not broken.

Comment: No criticism was meant; if the Content-Length is not set, chunks are streamed out. And `setContentLength` could only give an int length. With [`setContentLengthLong(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLengthLong-long-) this is recently improved (since Servlet 3.1). So one _could_ set the content length. That was all I wanted to say. Chunked itself is fine.

Comment: Apologies, my response may have sounded like I took criticism from you first comment but that's far from it. I just wanted to explain myself. It happens the application I'm using is a third party application and I have no way to set content length. SO seems like I may never get a workaround for this.

Comment: No apologies needed. Though another thought on transmission: 1. maybe compression is possible; 2. the site is still not doing it. Sending the request with header `Accept-Encoding: gzip` could return `Content-Encoding: gzip`.